# KivyMD Android App crashing because of error in material_resources.py file

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I developed a kivyMD app specifically for android which is running great on windows as .py but when converted to apk using ubuntu on windows, its giving an error that:

```
/mnt/c/Users/Ayan/Documents/rackcalculator/.buildozer/android/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/rackcalculator/arm64-v8a/kivymd/material_resources.py, line 20, in <module>

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'width'
```

Which is coming from kivyMD installed by buildozer.

I tried changing the code manually in material_resources.py and compiled it also. But still after running buildozer build it gives same problem. Clean build downloads the same material_resources.py with error.

Code that contains error is using `kivy.core.window import Window` then `Window.width` & `Window.height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure without looking at more of your code but it sounds like your code is trying to access Window properties &/or methods either before the Window has been created or after it has been deleted.

There are a number of points in the [documentation for kivi.core.Window](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html#module-kivy.core.window) where things are mentioned as being desktop only but height & width are not amongst them they are however marked as `AliasProperty` so actually make use of the setter/getter methods.
The

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'width'
```

message tells me that at that point in the code your window variable is None - i.e. doesn't currently/yet exist.

Keep in mind that things like window creation may not always occur in at the same point between platforms & implementation.
The other possibility is that your Window creation is failing *on android* and returning a `None` value.

### Update

For anybody experiencing the same sort of problem the OP did track down the cause of the failure to create the Window on Android - it was the use of setting an environmental variable to set a Kivi backend that was unsupported on the target platform.

Comment: Hi, I am quite new to kivy and got a basic idea of whats going wrong here, catch is where its happening, and i can't seem to find this answer. Would be great if you look at the code and point out the place causing this error. Thanks!          Code : https://github.com/AayanYasin/Kivy-App

Comment: @AaYanYasin - I have taken a quick look at your code and can find no mention of `Window.width` - I am reasonably sure that you have posted only the last couple of lines from the exception message - it probably tells you more. I do notice that almost none of your classes contain an `__init__(self)` method - this may be your problem. I would also suggest running [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) against your code and addressing all of the potential issues pointed out by it.

Comment: I found the error it was because i was adding `os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'` on top of my code. Which worked fine in my pc but other devices should not receive these lines

Comment: @AaYanYasin Great that you found it! Presumably that was causing the Window creation to fail.